# How to get all the SP groups for a specific user belongs to, across site collections in a tenant

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-groups

How to get all the SP groups a specific user belongs to, across all the site collections in a tenant. Please update us if it is possible by Graph API, REST API or any other means available.

Comment: Yes you can do this using PnP PowerShell `Get-SPOUser` please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42004084/sharepoint-online-find-all-site-collections-a-user-is-a-member-of

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Get-SPOUser will not work if we need to get SharePoint groups across site collections. I need to get SharePoint groups not Azure AD groups